# Sort table rows by drag and drop inside jquery collection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a problem sorting a table by drag and drop.
Let me explain:

I have an html table which is a jquery collection
this is the collection code:

```
$('.collection-container').collection({
    min: 1,
    init_with_n_elements: 1,
    down: '',
    up: '',
    remove: '',
    add: '',
    elements_selector: '> tr.element',
    hide_useless_buttons: false,
    drag_drop: true,
    drag_drop_options: {
        handle: '.sort-handle',
        sort: function() {
            $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
                opacity: 0.5
            });
            return true;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
                opacity: 1
            });
            const element = ui.item;
            const nextElement = $(element).next();
            let step = 1;
            if ($(nextElement).hasClass('io-registration-form-step')) {
                if ($(nextElement).data('step') === $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val()) {
                    step = $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
                } else {
                    const nextStepRow = $(element).prevAll('.io-registration-form-step').last();
                    if (nextStepRow.length) {
                        step = nextStepRow.data('step');
                    } else {
                        step = $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
                    }
                }
            } else if (nextElement.length) {
                step = $(nextElement).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
            }
            $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val(step);
            removeSteps();
            addSteps();
            deactivateEditors($('.element-row').first());
            activateEditors();
            return true;
        },
    },
    drag_drop_start: function(ui, event, elements, element) {
        return true;
    },
    drag_drop_update: function(ui, event, elements, element) {
        // Fired when dropping the element before stop event
        deactivateEditors($('.element-row').first());
        return true;
    },
    before_add: function(collection, element) {
        deactivateEditors(element);
        $(collection).closest('tbody').next().append($(collection).find('.add-fields-element-row'));
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
        return true;
    },
    after_add: function(collection, element) {
        // Set step for new element
        var $stepElement = $(element).find('[name$="[step]"]');
        if ($stepElement.length > 0) {
            var step = $('#io-registrationform-add-to-step').val();
            $stepElement.val(step);
        }
        $(element).find('textarea.tinymce').addClass('activate-tinymce');
        activateEditors();

        $(element).find('select').select2({
            width: '100%',
            minimumResultsForSearch: 10
        });
        var $isActiveCheckbox = $(element).find('[name$="[isActive]"]');
        if ($isActiveCheckbox.length > 0) {
            $isActiveCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
            $isActiveCheckbox.on('change', checkInForm);
            $isActiveCheckbox.change();
        }

        var type = $(element).find('[name$="[_type]"]').val();

        if (type === 'registrationform_registrationformcustomfield') {
            $(element).find('select[name$="[mainGuestDisplaySetting]"]').val('3').trigger('change');
        }

        if (type === 'registrationform_registrationformsubeventselection') {
            $(element).find('select[name$="[mainGuestFormElementWidthFactor]"]').val('12').trigger('change');
            $(element).find('select[name$="[companionFormElementWidthFactor]"]').val('12').trigger('change');
            $(element).find('select[name$="[mainGuestDisplaySetting]"]').val('3').trigger('change');
            $(element).find('select[name$="[companionDisplaySetting]"]').val('0').trigger('change');
            $(element).find('input[name$="[mainGuestFormElementFullWidth]"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(element).find('input[name$="[companionFormElementFullWidth]"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(element).find('input[name$="[label]"]').focus();
        }

        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $(window).scrollTo(element.offset().top - 50);
        return true;
    },
    before_remove: function(collection, element) {
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });

        deactivateEditors(element);

        var key = $(element).find('input[name$="[key]"]').val();
        var stepField = $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]');
        var labelField = $(element).find('input[name$="[label]"]');
        var typeField = $(element).find('select[name$="[type]"]');
        var optionField = $(element).find('textarea[name$="[options]"]');
        var accountLevelField = $(element).find('input[name$="[accountLevel]"]');
        var mandatoryField = $(element).find('input[name$="[mandatoryField]"]');
        var mainGuestFormElementWidthFactor = $(element).find('select[name$="[mainGuestFormElementWidthFactor]"]');
        var companionFormElementWidthFactor = $(element).find('select[name$="[companionFormElementWidthFactor]"]');
        var mainGuestDisplaySettingField = $(element).find('select[name$="[mainGuestDisplaySetting]"]');
        var companionDisplaySettingField = $(element).find('select[name$="[companionDisplaySetting]"]');
        var targetGroupField = $(element).find('select[name$="[targetGroup]"]');
        var fieldConditionField = $(element).find('input[name$="[fieldCondition]"]');

        $('#add-field-hidden option[value="' + key + '"]')
            .data('random-id', $(element).find('input[name$="[randomId]"]').val())
            .data('step', stepField.length ? stepField.val() : '1')
            .data('custom-field-id', $(element).find('input[name$="[customFieldId]"]').val())
            .data('type', typeField.length ? typeField.val() : '')
            .data('label', labelField.length ? labelField.val() : '')
            .data('options', optionField.length ? optionField.val() : '')
            .data('account-level', accountLevelField.length ? accountLevelField.is(':checked') : $(element).data('account-level'))
            .data('mandatory-field', mandatoryField.length ? mandatoryField.is(':checked') : '')
            .data('main-guest-form-element-width-factor', mainGuestFormElementWidthFactor.length ? mainGuestFormElementWidthFactor.val() : '')
            .data('companion-form-element-width-factor', companionFormElementWidthFactor.length ? companionFormElementWidthFactor.val() : '')
            .data('main-guest-display-setting', mainGuestDisplaySettingField.length ? mainGuestDisplaySettingField.val() : '')
            .data('companion-display-setting', companionDisplaySettingField.length ? companionDisplaySettingField.val() : '')
            .data('target-group', targetGroupField.length ? targetGroupField.val() : '')
            .data('field-condition', fieldConditionField.length ? fieldConditionField.val() : '');
        return true;
    },
    after_remove: function(collection, element) {

        activateEditors();
        $(element).find('select').select2({
            width: '100%',
            minimumResultsForSearch: 10
        });
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        setSelectableFields();
        return true;
    },
    before_up: function(collection, element) {
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
        deactivateEditors($(element).prev());
        return true;
    },
    after_up: function(collection, element) {

        activateEditors();
        $(element).find('select').select2({
            width: '100%',
            minimumResultsForSearch: 10
        });
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        return true;
    },
    before_down: function(collection, element) {
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
        deactivateEditors(element);
        return true;
    },
    after_down: function(collection, element) {

        activateEditors();
        $(element).find('select').select2({
            width: '100%',
            minimumResultsForSearch: 10
        });
        $('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

In the table there are table rows, some of them are steps, we can know that a tr is a step if it has the class "io-registration-form-step", and there are other table rows which are elements/fields, we can know that because they have the class "element". I am trying to make the drag and drop work. In the collection handlers there is the stop action which will be triggered after the drop is finished. I want to be able to change the order of the fields in the same step and between the steps. Each field has a hidden field named "registrationform[elements][i][step]".

For you to mention, I can add infinite steps and infinite elements inside steps

Let me add a screenshot of the UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i6YC.png)

On the stop handler I tried:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
$('tbody.collection-container').closest('table').css({
    opacity: 1
});
const element = ui.item;
const nextElement = $(element).next();
let step = 1;
if ($(nextElement).hasClass('io-registration-form-step')) {
    if ($(nextElement).data('step') === $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val()) {
        step = $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
    } else {
        const nextStepRow = $(element).prevAll('.io-registration-form-step').last();
        if (nextStepRow.length) {
            step = nextStepRow.data('step');
        } else {
            step = $(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
        }
    }
} else if (nextElement.length) {
    step = $(nextElement).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val();
}
$(element).find('input[name$="[step]"]').val(step);
removeSteps();
addSteps();
deactivateEditors($('.element-row').first());
activateEditors();
return true;
```

},